# ZF2 How to add model class of sub items to main model

Tags: php, zend-framework2, models

I've got a simple index action:

```
$reminders = $this->reminderTable->fetchAll();

foreach ($reminders as $reminder) {
    $reminder->receivers = $this->reminderTable->getReceivers($reminder->id);
}

return new ViewModel(array(
    'reminders' => $reminders
));
```

The get receivers (sub items of the main table) looks like this:

```
public function getReceivers($id)
{
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $receiversTable = new TableGateway('ga_reminders_receivers', $adapter);

    $resultSet = $receiversTable->select(function (Select $select) use ($id) {

        $select->join('ga_users', 'ga_reminders_receivers.receiver_uid = ga_users.uid', array('uid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'telephone'), 'left');
        $select->where('ga_reminders_receivers.rid = ' . $id);

    });

    return $resultSet;
}
```

This gives me the fancy error

> This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after
>   moving forward is not supported.

So, I guess my question is this: When I do a fetch of a resultset it fils in the model class thanks to `exchangearray()`. But how am I suppose to fill a model property with a list of sub models?

In this case the model is `Reminder`:

```
class Reminder { // from the reminders table

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id = (!empty($data['rid'])) ? str_pad($data['rid'], 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) : null;
    $this->label = (!empty($data['label'])) ? $data['label'] : null;
    // etc.
    $this->receivers = array(
        new Receiver(1),
        new Receiver(2),
        // list of objects from the reminders_receivers table
    )
}
```

Second question: Is the separate `getReceivers()` method needed? Maybe it can be integrated in 1 query. As long as the model classes `Reminder` and `Receiver` are used it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you have to use buffer.

```
public function getReceivers($id)
{
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $receiversTable = new TableGateway('ga_reminders_receivers', $adapter);

    $resultSet = $receiversTable->select(function (Select $select) use ($id) {

        $select->join('ga_users', 'ga_reminders_receivers.receiver_uid = ga_users.uid', array('uid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'telephone'), 'left');
        $select->where('ga_reminders_receivers.rid = ' . $id);

    });


    $resultSet->buffer();
    return $resultSet;
}
```